# Show 10 Sub Categories Per Parent Category Page?

Tags: categories

I have using following code for displaying sub categories in parent category page. Its displaying all subcategories in a single page. I want to display 10 sub categories per page. Please help me to limit the sub categories in category page.

My Code :

```
<?php 

$cat = get_query_var('cat');
$categories= get_categories('hide_empty=0&parent='.$cat);

if(!empty($categories)){

echo '<div class="post-listing"><section id="list"><ul>';

foreach ($categories as $categories_item) {

$mycat .= $category->cat_name;
echo $mycat;


        echo '<li>';
        echo '<h2 class="post-box-title"><a href="' . get_category_link( $categories_item->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "%s" ), $categories_item->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $categories_item->name.'</a> </h2> ';
        $terms = apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-get-terms', '' );
        if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) {
          foreach( (array) $terms as $term ) {
                if($term->term_id == $categories_item->term_id) {
                   print '<div class="post-thumbnail"><a class="thumb" href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $term, $term->taxonomy ) ) . '">' . wp_get_attachment_image( $term->image_id, 'medium' );
                   echo '</div></a>';
                 }
            }
            echo '<p>'. $categories_item->description; echo '</p></li>';
        }
    }

    echo '</ul></section></div>';
}else {
?>
```

Comment: `get_categories('hide_empty=0&parent='.$cat);` should be `get_categories('hide_empty=0&number=10&parent='.$cat);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this way :

```
get_categories('hide_empty=0&number=10&parent='.$cat);
```

For more reference visit this [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories)

Here number represents :

**number**

(string) The number of categories to return

Comment: Is there any reason why you pass arguments as concatenated string and not as an array? Arrays are much easier to read and quicker (there is no need to parse them)...